# Gathering information in a class from game players JAVA

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, save

I am creating a game with Java and JavaScript and I want on Java side to gather information to every player that joins the game. For example name, ID, number of piles, number of coins.
The information about the players I get from the client sidde / JavaScript.

I created a class in Java that looks like this:

```
 public class GamePlayer 
 {
   private String _name;
   private Integer _sfsID;
   private int welche_piles;
   private int azahl_jetons;
   private Collection<GamePlayer> AllGamePlayers;



 public GamePlayer(String name, Integer sfs_id, Vector<Integer> welche_piles, Vector<Integer> anzahl_jetons) 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   //here I will do stuff with the information


 }

}
//in the game.class
GamePlayer gameplayer = new GamePlayer(user.get_name(), user.get_sfsID(),piles,coins);

    AllGamePlayers.add(gameplayer);
    for(GamePlayer gp : AllGamePlayers)
    {
       gp.gatherInformation(gp);    
    }
```

I thought to save every player in a Collection --> AllGamePlayers.
Now I want to know how to access the information I get. For example how to get the name for the user with the sfsID 2? Acctually I want to get all information about every user.
How should I do this? Any advice how to improve the class?

Comment: AllGamePlayers should be in another class, like Game, or marked as static field.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yes you are right! I completely deleted the function "getGamePlayer" and I stored the "gameplayer" in my "game.class"

Comment: with gp in Game.class I can access all of the information I need.
is this a correct way to access the variables in GamePlayer.class?

Answer (score 0):

Store all the Player-Objects in a HashMap or therelike in a static field in GamePlayer or in a different Class that represents the game.

A HashMap would be useful because it lets you get the Players quickly.

Comment: Don't forget about equals/hashCode!